# Inserting multiple string into mysql using bind_param

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

I'm retrieving tweets from the twitter api, which i'm trying to save in my database however i keep getting an error, which i cant seem to fix. i've checked  the number of parameters is correct and everything should be okay, so i dont see why i get following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

**tweets database:**

[image]

```
function retrievePlayerTweets(){
    global $con;
    $query = $con->prepare("Select players.fullname, players.twitter_user, team.id as teamId FROM players, team WHERE players.teamId = team.id");
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($fullname, $twitter_user, $teamId);


    while ($query->fetch()) {

        foreach(retrieveUserTweets($twitter_user) as $twitterData) {
            $id = $twitterData['id_str'];
            $text = $twitterData['text'];
            $name = $twitterData['user']['name'];
            $dateString = $twitterData['created_at'];
            $favoriteCount = $twitterData['favorite_count'];
            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dateString));



              $insert_tweet = $con->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO tweets (`fullname`, `username`, `text`, `created`, `teamId`, `twitterId`, `favoriteCount`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
              $insert_tweet->bind_param("ssssisi", $name, $twitter_user, $text, $date, $teamId, $id, $favoriteCount);
                $insert_tweet->execute() or die(mysqli_error($con));







        }
    }





}
```

Comment: So your prepare statement failed. You need to add error handling to see what went wrong.

Comment: I think you should put "ssssisi" in a variable first.

Comment: What should that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `$con` variable which is not connecting to the database, due to which the methods inside cannot be called.

also it is good pratice to add `die()` function to print error message after call to the execute function in PDO or mysqli, to see error in query use:

if using PDO:
`$insert_tweet->execute() or die(print_r($con->errorInfo()));`

if using mysqli:

`$insert_tweet->execute() or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: nope i already have this `$con = mysqli_connect('host','user','pass','db');`

Comment: yes you have but check if it successfully connects, and put the real values in those parameters if you haven't in `mysqli_connect` function

Comment: should be working since i'm using the `$con` in the beginning of the function in another query

Comment: i keep getting same error on this line `$insert_tweet->bind_param("ssssisi", $name, $twitter_user, $text, $date, $teamId, $id, $favoriteCount);`

Comment: it is simple error your prepare query is failing because, $con is not correct , due which $insert_tweet is not assigned object to which has the methd `bind_param()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79111/discussion-between-sourabh-and-peter-pik).

Comment: run this code, before the prepare query and see what is the output:
`if (!$con)
  {
  echo "Failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }`